# Display one value of an array while empty values are skipped

Tags: php, arrays

I have the following arrays (making use of gravity forms):

```
$opleidingscode1 = rgar( $entry, '31');
$opleidingscode2 = rgar( $entry, '32');
...
$opleidingscode9 = rgar( $entry, '39');
```

I then:

```
$array = array( "$opleidingscode1","$opleidingscode2",...,"$opleidingscode9" );
```

So 8 arrays will be empty, only one can have input. So I `implode`:

```
$arrayimploded = array("'.implode('", "', $array).'");
```

I then send it via API:

```
'aWebAanvraag'=>array("OpleidingsSoortCode" => "$arrayimploded")
```

However, the data received shows *"array"* instead of the correct value.

What am I missing here?

Comment: because you set the array `array("OpleidingsSoortCode" => "$arrayimploded")` into `'aWebAanvraag'`. try `'aWebAanvraag'=>$arrayimploded`

Comment: _“What am I missing here?”_ - that the thinking “oh, a variable, I better put that into quotes quickly, it might feel naked and cold otherwise” is typical noob nonsense, and means you should go read up on how to properly work with the basic syntax now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At first you are passing your variables in double quotes and that means you are not giving the value assigned to them to your final array.

Also the function implode glues your array together and does not require to be an array itself (that is if you don't want it to be an array).

Try this instead :

```
$array = array( $opleidingscode1,$opleidingscode2,...,$opleidingscode9);
```

And

```
array("OpleidingsSoortCode" => $arrayimploded);
```

your variables will have original values not string values with this format.

Comment: you're welcome. don't hesitate to vote for h-khadem answer ;-)

Comment: you are welcome @Kees. if this solved your problem please mark my answer as accepted and don't forget to vote. thanks in advance